# орфография проверяется местоимением?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня в школе 30 лет назад слово "втечение" учили писать слитно, почему сейчас оно пишется раздельно?

Comment: Потому что это слово стали реже употреблять как синоним "втекания" :)

Comment: _МАКС: Меня в школе 30 лет назад слово "втечение" учили писать слитно..._ === Скорее всего, слитно Вас могли 30 лет назад учить писать предлог _**вследствие**_.  Он и сейчас так же пишется. А _**в течение**_ и тогда писалось и сейчас пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего Вы ошиблись и запомнили не ту орфограмму.

Предлог (а не местоимение) «в течение»  и существительное «течение» с предлогом «в» всегда писались раздельно.

Трудность обычно возникает с окончанием - *е* или *и*?

Напомню [правило](http://reshit.ru/vtechenii-v-techenii-slitno-ili-razdel%27no):

> В случае, когда «в течение» у нас предлог, мы всегда пишем «е» на
> конце! Когда мы имеем предлог «в» и существительное «течение», то
> возможно, как «е», так и «и» на конце.
>
> Важно понимать, что «в течение» в большинстве случаев является именно
> предлогом, за исключением тех случаев, где «течение» в предложении
> является самостоятельным существительным и употребляется в буквальном
> смысле. Проще всего это понять на примерах. Рассмотрим несколько.
>
> В течение часа нужно выполнить эту работу (предлог). Вова готовился к
> экзаменам в течение всего дня (предлог). Наша лодка неслась в течении
> этого огромного потока воды (предлог и сущ.). Грязная вода попала в
> течение (предлог и сущ.). В течении реки последние несколько лет
> наблюдаются изменения (предлог и сущ.).
>
> В первых двух примерах мы имеем предлог. По смыслу он означает - на
> протяжении некоторого времени. Мы всегда пишем «е» на конце! В
> оставшихся трёх у нас существительное «течение» с предлогом «в». «Е»
> или «и» в конце зависит от падежа.
>
> В чем? – В течении – Предложный падеж.
>
> Во что? – В течение –
> Винительный падеж.

**[Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_130)** уточняет:

> Пишутся раздельно предложные сочетания В ВИДЕ, В ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ, В МЕРУ, В
> ОБЛАСТИ, В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ, В ОТНОШЕНИИ, В ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ, В СВЯЗИ С, В СИЛУ,
> В СМЫСЛЕ, В ТЕЧЕНИЕ, В ЦЕЛЯХ, В ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ, В ЦЕЛЯХ, ЗА ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ,
> ЗА СЧЕТ, ПО МЕРЕ, ПО ПОВОДУ, ПО ПРИЧИНЕ. От исходных сочетаний
> предлога и существительного отличаются лишь некоторые из производных
> предлогов.
>
> Обратите внимание на последнюю гласную Е в предлогах В
> ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ, В ОТЛИЧИЕ ОТ, В ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ, В ТЕЧЕНИЕ, В ЗАВЕРШЕНИЕ.

Answer (score 2):

Да, интересное слово.

1) **Раньше "втечение" могло быть синонимом существительного "втекание"**

Сии последние вместо того, чтобы делать в оное время окружающий нас воздух растворенным, распространяют еще более повсюду пагубное свое **втечение**. [В. Ф. Зуев. Причины, от коих воздух в покоях испортиться может (1787)]

В третьем же классе состоят перипатетики, доказывающие соединение души с телом чрез физическое **втечение**,  [Д. С. Аничков. . апреля 22 дня 1783 года (1783)]

**2) Старая норма**

Хорошее масло должно сбиваться **втечение** 30-45 минуть при вращении ручки маслобойки +5-50 раз в минуту. [С. П. Фридолин. Краткое руководство по молочному хозяйству для крестьян, хуторян и мелких хозяев (1913)]

**Втечение** двух часов поезд не мог двинуться с места. [И. Б. Саранчовое нашествие // Всемирный следопыт, 1929]

**3) Современная норма**

**В Правилах 1956 года** указано раздельное написание предлога "в течение" с буквой Е на конце (предлог можно найти в словаре, прилагаемом к Правилам).

4) **Как можно объяснить выбор раздельного написания**

Существует выражение "течение времени", например: "Ночь выглядит так, как будто **течение времени** не прерывалось общественными бурями перестроечных времён.  Фактически элементарный предлог "В" (в составе производного предлога "в течение") управляет этим сочетанием в форме В.п.: в (течение времени) (В.п.), за какое-то время (В.п.).

Таким образом, по семантике мы имеем **производный предлог** (его можно заменить другими предлогами, например "в продолжение"), **а по формальной грамматике элементарный предлог "В" управляет словосочетанием "течение времени"** и поэтому пишется раздельно.